# How to tell a parent ViewController layout is finished without using a layoutFinished flag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I want to  calculate UITableViewCell's height with using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`. the cell calculates the right height requires the viewcontroller has successfuly layout. otherwise the width of the cell maybe wrong.

So the question is , is there any ways that the cell could tell whether the VC had successfully finished layout, except the method that the VC could set a property `viewDidLayoutFinished` after the UITableViewDelegate calls.

I could get the current ViewController by the `nextResponder` mechanism by the way.so ,what's next?

Answer (score 0):

You can post a notification from either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear of said UIViewController indicating the UIViewController finished layout